# phpcs Use ::class notation instead warning on attribute source field

Tags: magento2, php, setup

I've created a setup script to load from a source model

```php
$eavSetup->addAttribute(
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\Category::ENTITY,
    'location_reference',
    [
        'type' => 'varchar',
        'label' => 'Location Reference',
        'input' => 'select',
        'sort_order' => 500,
        'source' => 'Xigen\Data\Model\Category\Attribute\Source\LocationReference',
        'global' => 1,
        'visible' => true,
        'required' => false,
        'user_defined' => false,
        'default' => null,
        'group' => 'General Information',
        'backend' => '',
    ]
);
```

Works great.  However using the official https://github.com/magento/magento-coding-standard ruleset it showed the following warning.

`Use ::class notation instead`

And sure enough checking a file in vendor at random

`Magento\Catalog\Setup\UpgradeData`

```php
$categorySetup->addAttribute(
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product::ENTITY,
    'custom_layout',
    [
        'type' => 'varchar',
        'label' => 'New Layout',
        'input' => 'select',
        'source' => \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Attribute\Source\Layout::class,
        'required' => false,
        'sort_order' => 50,
        'global' => \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\ScopedAttributeInterface::SCOPE_STORE,
        'group' => 'Schedule Design Update',
        'is_used_in_grid' => true,
        'is_visible_in_grid' => false,
        'is_filterable_in_grid' => false
    ]
);
```

Can someone explain more in detail why this syntax is used? Why it is recommended?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Strings can contain typos.
2. You can not use the "jump to class" feature on strings from your IDE.
3. Refactoring in an IDE will find `::class` notations and not strings.

Comment: @tvanriel I greatly apprecheate your edit! valid point!

Comment: hmm .. i still don't know what to do with this when we check by magento standard code.

Comment: @fudu what is your actual problem ?

Comment: @MuhammadOmerAslam now i know what to do, but before, when i read this answer, i don't understand what he saying and what to do to resolve the problem.

Comment: @fudu you need to change the `'source' => 'Xigen\Data\Model\Category\Attribute\Source\LocationReference',` to `'source' => Xigen\Data\Model\Category\Attribute\Source\LocationReference::class,` hope that clears the confusion

Comment: @MuhammadOmerAslam yes, thanks. That's more helpful to understand.